# Пытаюсь откалибровать **стереопару** и построить **карту глубины**

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv

Пытаюсь откалибровать **стереопару**  и построить **карту глубины** для последующего вычисления расстояния до какого-либо предмета .Не получается построить карту  , получается что-то вроде того , что на рисунке ниже. Использую разные камеры.

Comment: покажите исходную картинку, и/или попробуйте запустить алгоритм на картинке из примера